# Using Glide inside a Runnable that is placed outside onViewCreated()

Tags: java, android

I am using `Glide` function to load an image form a server response. The code below is working properly inside an `onViewCreated` function, but i want to make a `Handler` to verify the internet connection and I am declaring the `Runnable` as a global variable. Well inside that `Runnable` I can't use `getActivity` as a context/container. What should I use?

Here is the code inside `onViewCreated()`:

```
        try {
            Glide.with(this.getActivity()).load(jsonObject.getString("dispensary_thumbmail")).into(image);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And here is the `Runnable`:

```
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(!isNetworkConnected())
        {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable , time);
        }
        else
        {
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(MainActivity.dispensaries);
                jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("dispensaries");
                Log.e(TAG, "jsonArray = " + jsonArray);
                jsonObject = null;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(MainActivity.ID.equals(object.get("dispensary_id")))
                    {
                        jsonObject = object;
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                Glide.with(this.).load(jsonObject.getString("dispensary_thumbmail")).into(image);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, basically, you needed **runOnUiThread** of activity class

```
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Glide.with(getActivity()).load(jsonObject.getString("dispensary_thumbmail")).into(image);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am in a Fragment. It is obvious because an activity needs onCreate() not onViewCreated() as a Fragment.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It was a little tricky, but it helped. Here is what it should have been done:
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(jsonObject.getString("dispensary_thumbmail")).into(image);

I realized right after I saw your code.

Comment: Cool, You should read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work